# Templated Copy-Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Imagine the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct A : public Base
{
    void foo() override {};
};

struct B : public Base
{
    void foo() override {};
};

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    struct Element
    {
        int x, y, z;

        bool operator==(const Element& e)
        {
            if (x != e.x) return false;
            if (y != e.y) return false;
            if (z != e.z) return false;
            return true;
        }
    };

    Base* p;
    std::vector<Element> v;

    C()
    {
        p = new T();
    }

    void add(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Element e;
        e.x = x;
        e.y = y;
        e.z = z;
        v.push_back(e);
    }

    void remove(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        Element e;
        e.x = x;
        e.y = y;
        e.z = z;
        std::vector<Element>::iterator it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), e);
        if (p != v.end()) v.erase(p);
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (Element e : v) std::cout << e.x << " " << e.y << " " << e.z << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<A> a;

    a.add(1, 2, 3);
    a.add(4, 5, 6);
    a.add(7, 8, 9);

    a.remove(4, 5, 6);

    a.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Now let's add a copy-constructor in C so that we can initialize C with another C that holds another data-type (as long as the data-type derives from Base). The goal is to make this possible:

```
int main()
{
    C<A> a;

    a.add(1, 2, 3);
    a.add(4, 5, 6);
    a.add(7, 8, 9);

    a.remove(4, 5, 6);

    a.print();

    C<B> b(a); // <----- This should be possible.

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to solve it like this:

```
template <typename U>
C(const C<U>& c)
{
    p = new U(*c.p);
    v = c.v;
}
```

But I get these 2 errors from Visual Studio:

> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::vector::Element,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> Error C2664   'A::A(A &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Base' to 'const A &'

From what I've understood, std::vector already has an assignment-operator implemented that should make a deep copy of the vector on the right side of the operator.

So what am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: You'll probably need to add a `virtual Base* clone() const = 0;` to your Base class, and override it in the derived classes to do the actual cloning, then call that to copy `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
v = c.v;
```

These are two completely different types.

`v` is `std::vector<C<T>::Element>`.

`c.v` is `std::vector<C<U>::Element>`.

Given different `T` and `U` types, `C<T>` and `C<U>` are completely different types, that have no relation to each other.

`C<T>::Element` and `C<U>::Element` are also completely different types. So is a `std::vector` of each, too.

`C<T>::Element` and `C<U>::Element` may have the same class name. They may have the same exact class members. But they are two independent types, just as different between each other as `class A` is different from `class B`.
The problem is not the template copy-constructor itself. The problem is that the copy constructor attempts to assign one type to each other.

What you need to do is remove the inner class `Element`. It does not depend on a template parameter. Make it an independent top level class. Then, both `C<T>` and `C<U>` will have a class member `v` which is a vector of the same type, and they can be assigned to each other.

Comment: +1 for the opening emphasis. When I entered the realm of templates metaprogramming, understanding that someClass<U> and someClass<T> are completely different types took some time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, moving the Element class worked. What surprised me was that the 2 vectors was considered different types even though Element was exactly the same in both vectors.

Comment: `class A { class Element { int x; } }; class B { class Element { int x; } }` -- `A::Element` and `B::Element` are two different classes, that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Yeah, when you put it that way it makes a lot of sense. I was thinking more about the internal byte structure in the `Element` class, and hence I thought that it would be logically possible to assign a certain set of bytes to another identical set of bytes even if they did not share the same name. Is this just a C++ syntax limitation or also disabled in C/Assembly?